# What quantities are conserved through for light passing through a converging lens?

Tags: optics, visible-light, fourier-transform

I am currently learning Fourier Optics. I have a beam with a Gaussian profile which passes through a converging lens. The resultant cross section at the focal point is being calculated. I am using an effective Fourier Transform in the lens plane to calculate the output at the focal point. This effective Fourier Transform is derived using the Fresnel Integral. I am carrying out numerical calculations in Matlab. The input electric field has a Gaussian cross section, and the intensity is calculated as $$ I = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon_0}{\mu_0}}|\textbf{E}|^2.$$

What quantities would be the same between my near field ( in the lens ) cross section of light and my far field ( at the focal point ) cross section of light? I am assuming that power into the lens would have to be equal to power at the focal point. I'm finding total power by integrating the intensity over the area for both the lens and focal plane. That is to say: $$ P = \iint I(x,y)  dA.$$

I am looking for other ways to check that my code is calculating quantities correctly.

A follow up question is; How could these quantities in the far field be calculated in the equivalent k-space of the far field? If there is only a certain amount of power within the far field, would the Fourier transform of the far field into k-space have that same total amount of power? If so, how could this be verified?

Comment: If I resolved this on my own, should I delete the question, or answer it on my own to provide others with help?

Comment: Answer your own question - I am interested in your solution!